How to switch audio and subtitle tracks with buttons in a YouTube video using IFrame API?
I am working on a webpage that uses JavaScript to embed a YouTube video with multiple language audio tracks (MLA) and subtitles. My example video ID is PWirijQkH4M. I want to allow users to switch audio tracks with one button and switch subtitles with another button.
I have implemented the following code, but it does not seem to work as expected. The video does not switch tracks when the buttons are clicked. How can I achieve this functionality?
Any guidance on how to correctly implement the audio and subtitle track switching functionality would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Here is my current code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>YouTube Multi-language Audio and Subtitle Switching</title>

  <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

  <style>
    /* Button styles */
    .button {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      margin: 5px;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .button:hover {
      background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="player"></div>

  <button class="button" id="audioTrackButton">Switch Audio Track</button>

  <button class="button" id="subtitleTrackButton">Switch Subtitles</button>

  <script>
    // Prepare YouTube player
    var player;
    var videoId = 'PWirijQkH4M'; // Example video ID

    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '360',
        width: '640',
        videoId: videoId,
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        }
      });
    };

    // Triggered when player is ready
    function onPlayerReady() {
      // Check if the video supports multiple audio tracks and subtitles
      if (player.tracks.length > 1) {
        // Initialize audio and subtitle track indexes
        var currentAudioTrackIndex = 0;
        var currentSubtitleTrackIndex = 0;

        // Event handler for switching audio track button
        document.getElementById('audioTrackButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
          currentAudioTrackIndex = (currentAudioTrackIndex + 1) % player.tracks.length;
          player.tracks[currentAudioTrackIndex].languageCode.select();
        });

        // Event handler for switching subtitles button
        document.getElementById('subtitleTrackButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
          currentSubtitleTrackIndex = (currentSubtitleTrackIndex + 1) % player.tracks.length;
          player.tracks[currentSubtitleTrackIndex].languageCode.select();
        });
      } else {
        console.warn('The video does not support multiple audio tracks or subtitles');
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>

Error Message:
index20240629-02.html:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at onPlayerReady (index20240629-02.html:57:25)
    at p.H (www-widgetapi.js:171:276)
    at www-widgetapi.js:187:26


but it does not seem to work as expected what does it do? any errors in the console?

Thank you for your response. I checked the "YouTube IFrame API" and couldn't find any way to solve this issue. Do you have any suggestions to help resolve these issues? Thank you!

What does your code do now? Are there any errors in the developer tools console?

Hi Jaromanda,
Thank you for your previous assistance. I've encountered some errors while running the code and was hoping to get your input again. Here's the error message:
(anonymous) @ www-widgetapi.js:225Understand this warning
index20240629-02.html:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at onPlayerReady (index20240629-02.html:57:25)
Do you have any suggestions regarding this? I greatly appreciate your time and expertise.
Thank you!

Please add the details of the error into the question where you can make it readable - at first glance, it seems player.tracks undefined, which would explain why your code does nothing

Here's the detailed error message:
index20240629-02.html:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at onPlayerReady (index20240629-02.html:57:25)
at p.H (www-widgetapi.js:171:276)
at www-widgetapi.js:187:26
I have also checked the "YouTube IFrame API" documentation but couldn't find any related methods or parameters that might help solve this issue.
Do you have any suggestions regarding this? I greatly appreciate your time and expertise.

I said Please add the details of the error into the question where you can make it readable ... not sure why you just repeated in a comment - also, check what player.tracks is

what makes you believe player.tracks even exists :p

Sorry, I already added the error message into the question. I have also checked the "YouTube IFrame API" documentation but couldn't find any related methods or parameters that might help solve this issue. Currently, I can only use player.getOptions(); to switch subtitles, but I am unable to switch audio tracks.
Do you have any suggestions or know of any methods that could help me switch the audio tracks in a YouTube video? I greatly appreciate your time and expertise.

You don't need to repeat the problem in every comment, we know what you want to do, we know it doesn't work. I just wonder why you thought player.tracks even existed - must be from some documentation somewhere? Or did you just use player.tracks and hope it did what you want?

I wasn't sure how to switch audio tracks, so I asked around and Gemini suggested trying player.tracks. However, I couldn't find any relevant methods in the YouTube IFrame API documentation. If you have any suggestions on how to switch audio tracks, I would greatly appreciate it.

If nothing is documented, then nothing can be done, despite Gemini (whatever that is when it's at home) says :p

Sir, do you work for YouTube? If so, could you help add this function to the YouTube IFrame API? I would greatly appreciate it.

@Simon I do not work for YouTube, but, this answer might help; also, about the "audio", I don't think that is possible. If I understood well your question you want to change/switch audio and subtitiles: example: play the video with audio and subtitles in german, then, switch both audio and subtitles to other language available in the video - let's say: spanish. If this is what you want, that cannot be done outside the iframe. YouTube API and iframe is rather limited for such met specific requirements.

Although it's not the outcome I was hoping for, your explanation helped me understand the reality of the situation better. Thank you so much for your detailed answer! Your response was very helpful in understanding the limitations of the YouTube API.
